# Javascript - Is it possible to use fetch or axios.get with a specific property path?

Tags: javascript, axios, fetch

I am a student, in my 3rd week of learning JavaScript, and today I've been completely roadblocked by something I can't find my way around.

Suppose I have the following:

```
axios.get("www.examplewebsite.com/api/......")
 .then((response)=>{
   console.log(response)
})
```

The json in question contains a tremendous amount of data, and all I need is one url from it. I found the property path of:

data.data.examples[0].example.week3.uri

Is there any way to use axios, or even fetch, to grab that single piece of data?

Comment: no, the server sends what it is programmed to send

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the API provides that option, the client cannot specify which bits of information are wanted. With a regular REST API you get what the server sends you.

But, you can chain `.then()` calls if you want to narrow your data down and disregard everything you don't care about:

```
axios.get("www.examplewebsite.com/api/......")
     .then(response => response.data.data.examples[0].example.week3.uri)
     .then(uri => {
         console.log(uri)
     })
```

Or, if you want to grab the URI from the same path for all your examples, you could narrow it down to an array of URIs:

```
axios.get("www.examplewebsite.com/api/......")
     .then(response => response.data.data.examples)
     .then(examples => examples.map(item => item.example.week3.uri))
     .then(uris => {
         console.log(uris)
     })
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer. So basically, I can't filter out what the API sends back to me, but I can filter what it displays. That makes perfect sense.

Comment: @KirkForADay this also means that if you ever want to keep other parts of the response, you might benefit from storing the result instead of fetching it again for each part of the JSON you might need (could end up getting pretty costly).

But surely it would be better for the backend to actually offer an endpoint for that piece of data specifically.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the server and the backend. It might be possible to get the value, but you have to provide the required information in your request (URL).
For example, this URL (http://site.come/moives) can give you a list of movies, but this (http://site.come/moives/movieid) can give you information about a certain movie. Again it depends on the server ...